# Python is returning an AttributeError while importing some modules all of sudden. How do I fix it?

Tags: python, quandl

My script was running well before. I had a series of crashes on some scripts where I had to fix some things. However, all of a sudden, I can't even run a script and my sublime text shell is displaying this error. I tried chasing down the files in my /Library/...python... files to see if any files got renamed or any part of the module scripts got renamed or something, but have yet to figure it out. What can I try. Or better question, what did I do all of a sudden to cause this, and how would I undo it? It was literally working fine less than an hour ago not to mention all day.

```
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/numerictypes.py", line 101, in <module>
    import numbers
  File "/Users/peter/Documents/Trading/Code/AlphaModelVer1/numbers.py", line 2, in <module>
    import Quandl
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Quandl/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .Quandl import (
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Quandl/Quandl.py", line 11, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from . import hashtable, tslib, lib
      File "pandas/src/numpy.pxd", line 157, in init pandas.hashtable (pandas/hashtable.c:22984)
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'dtype'
```

EDIT:

Thanks to the comments! I had tried re-installing pandas, numpy, and Quandl. But it was all due to the fact I had renamed a helper script numbers.py, when it needed to draw that from within. Hint to all future users: Do not rename python scripts to existing module types.

Comment: It would be helpful if you included the code.

Comment: It looks like you created a file called `numbers.py` that is shadowing a builtin module of that name.  If you rename your file to something else, does that fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar error that was caused by installing a package while I had IPython running. Try reinstalling Pandas using pip (make sure all Python instances are closed) and maybe you'll have to reiinstall hashtable as well, I can't remember.

Answer (score 0):

try to reinstall this Quandl library

> File
>   "/Users/peter/Documents/Trading/Code/AlphaModelVer1/numbers.py", line
>   2, in 
>       import Quandl

```
pip uninstall Quandl

pip install Quandl
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurred with me in spite of not naming the script name to the existing module name. I tried the following and it worked.

Instead of "import Quandl", I did "from Quandl import Quandl" and it worked for me!